# Android Data Binding crash when using include tag with custom view layout

Tags: android, xml, include, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I'm trying to add some custom view using `include` tag to my activity layout which using DataBinding. My custom view is using DataBinding as well. But I got crash on application start:

```
05-02 17:30:03.685 12595-12595/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.novachevskyi.databindingtest, PID: 12595
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.novachevskyi.databindingtest/com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.databinding.CustomViewBinding.invalidateAll()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.databinding.CustomViewBinding.invalidateAll()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.invalidateAll(ActivityMainBinding.java:41)
                                                       at com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.<init>(ActivityMainBinding.java:33)
                                                       at com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.bind(ActivityMainBinding.java:105)
                                                       at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:11)
                                                       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:185)
                                                       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:299)
                                                       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:279)
                                                       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:261)
                                                       at com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

CustomView:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    DataBindingUtil.bind(this);
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_view"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

custom_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.CustomView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </com.novachevskyi.databindingtest.CustomView>

</layout>
```

I've also created public repo with sample project:
https://github.com/novachevskyi/DataBinding-issue

I was using data binding with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1` and now, when I've tried to upgrade build tools version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0`, I'm facing such issue with all my views that contain `include` xml tag. Will appreciate for any information about issue described above.

Comment: This line create problem  DataBindingUtil.bind(this); I really don't understand what are you want, because you not use functionality of data-binding. Give more information

Answer (score 4):

I took a look at your project and ran it. I think the reason it is crashing is because of

```
@Override protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    DataBindingUtil.bind(this);
}
```

if you remove `DataBindingUtil.bind(this)` it will stop crashing. The reason being that the bind call is looking for a `<layout>`surrounding the view but it can't find it so it throws an exception. Since the CustomView is calling bind on itself it is not surrounded by anything causing `ViewDataBinding` to `throw new IllegalArgumentException("View is not a binding layout")`

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but calling `bind` inside of `onFinishInflate` would be redundant since the activity is doing that for you when it binds the layout for the activity. If you require the binding within the `CustomView` class you can do the following:

```
@Override protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  CustomViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution which worked for me with custom views and data binding.

Comment: Why do we need `DataBindingUtil.bind` instead of `DataBindingUtil.inflate`?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else makes the er..dumb mistake I did...

This error was happening to me when I mistakenly had two duplicate layout files, one using databinding, and the other not...

Removing the duplicate fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the crash was due using same id (@+id/progress_bar) in both include tag and in the layout file.

activity layout

```
<include **android:id="@+id/progress_bar"** layout="@layout/progress_bar" />
```

progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

when I change activity layout like this, it was fixed

```
<include **android:id="@+id/pb"** layout="@layout/progress_bar" />
```

Answer (score -1):

@SeptimusX75's answer doesn't work, because `DataBindingUtil.findBinding(this)` calls `this.getTag(R.id.dataBinding)` internally to get the binding, but the tag hasn't been set yet when `onFinishInflate` is called.

Instead, try to get the binding via `this.getTag(R.id.dataBinding);` when you need the use the binding.

```java
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    // ...
    public CustomViewBinding binding;
    // ...
    public void setTitle(final String text) {
        if (binding == null) {
            binding = Objects.requireNonNull(getTag(R.id.dataBinding));
        }
        binding.title.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, set the binding manually from the activity before calling any method on the CustomView.

```java
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    // ...
    public CustomViewBinding binding;
    // ...
    public void setBinding(final CustomViewBinding binding) {
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CustomViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.customView.getRoot().setBinding(binding.customView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Goto Build option in toolbar and select Rebuild Project.